# Use value of related field when saving/POST django-rest-framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to find a method for posting a string value and saving it to a foreign key field instead of using the pk.

My models:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username



class Order(models.Model):
    ordernumber = models.UUIDField(primary_key=False, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
          return "{0}".format(self.ordernumber)
```

And my serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(source='user.username')


    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id','username', 'ordernumber', 'amount')
        read_only_fields = ('id')
```

When using GET, everything works perfectly, but I can't seem to fix the POST method.

I tried to override the create method like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    username = validated_data.pop('username')
    order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
    order.user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
    order.save()

    return order
```

But I get a KeyError on the `username = validated_data.pop('username')` line: `Exception Value:'username'`

Comment: You probably want to use [`SlugRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield)

Comment: Yes, would also work like this: `username = serializers.SlugRelatedField(source='user', slug_field='username', queryset=CustomUser.objects.all())`, but it would get every username in a select list. But thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `source` with nested fields, data will be accessible as `validated_data['parent_field']['child_field']`. Try this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):

    user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
    username = user_data.pop('username')
    order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
    order.user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)
    order.save()

    return order
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!